# The print statements for my printAnimals method won't stop executing

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

Whenever my printAnimals method executes, it won't stop repeating whats being printed. I've tried moving the break statements, and changing how the program determines what to print, but so far nothing has worked.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    private static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);  // scanner object

    // array lists for dogs and monkeys
    private static ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    private static ArrayList<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<Monkey>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String menuChoice = ""; // local variable

        // static methods
        initializeDogList();
        initializeMonkeyList();

        displayMenu();  // call display menu method
        menuChoice = scnr.nextLine();  // get menu choice from user
        // loop that displays the menu, accepts user inputs, takes appropriate action
        while(!menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){  // q causes loop to quit executing
            switch(menuChoice) {  // execute menuChoice based on user input
                case "1":  // if user enters 1, execute intakeNewDog method
                    intakeNewDog(scnr);
                    break;
                case "2":  // if user enters 2, execute intakeNewMonkey method
                    intakeNewMonkey(scnr);
                    break;
                case "3":  // if user enters 3, execute reserveAnimal method
                    reserveAnimal(scnr);
                    break;
                case "4":  // if user enters 4, execute printAnimals method
                    printAnimals("4");
                    break;
                case "5":  // if user enters 5, execute printAnimals method
                    printAnimals("5");
                    break;
                case "6":  // if user enters 6, execute printAnimals method
                    printAnimals("6");
                    break;
                default:  // if user input is invalid, print message
                    if(!menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
                        System.out.println("\n Invalid input, enter 1-6 or q");
                        displayMenu();  // call display menu method
                        menuChoice = scnr.nextLine();  // get menu choice from user
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // This method prints the menu options
    public static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tRescue Animal System Menu");
        System.out.println("[1] Intake a new dog");
        System.out.println("[2] Intake a new monkey");
        System.out.println("[3] Reserve an animal");
        System.out.println("[4] Print a list of all dogs");
        System.out.println("[5] Print a list of all monkeys");
        System.out.println("[6] Print a list of all animals that are not reserved");
        System.out.println("[q] Quit application");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a menu selection");
    }


    // Adds dogs to a list for testing
    public static void initializeDogList() {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Spot", "German Shepherd", "male", "1", "25.6", "05-12-2019", "United States", "intake", false, "United States");
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Rex", "Great Dane", "male", "3", "35.2", "02-03-2020", "United States", "Phase I", false, "United States");
        Dog dog3 = new Dog("Bella", "Chihuahua", "female", "4", "25.6", "12-12-2019", "Canada", "in service", true, "Canada");

        dogList.add(dog1);
        dogList.add(dog2);
        dogList.add(dog3);
    }


    // Adds monkeys to a list for testing
    public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
        Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Monty", "male", "5", "27","02-10-2024", "United States", "intake", false, "United States", "3", "1.9", "16", "macaque");

        monkeyList.add(monkey1);
    }

    // create intakeNewDog method
    public static void intakeNewDog(Scanner scnr) {
        // get dog's name and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's name?");
        String name = scnr.nextLine();
        // input validation if dog is already in dogList
        for(Dog dog: dogList) {
            if(dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis dog is already in our system\n\n");
                return; //returns to menu
            }
        }

        // code to instantiate new dog and add to list
        // get dog's breed and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's breed?");
        String breed = scnr.nextLine();
        // get dog's gender and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's gender?");
        String gender = scnr.nextLine();
        // get dog's age and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's age?");
        String age = scnr.nextLine();
        //get dog's weight and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's weight?");
        String weight = scnr.nextLine();
        // get dog's acquisition date and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's acquisition date?");
        String acquisitionDate = scnr.nextLine();
        // get dog's acquisition country and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's acquisition country?");
        String acquisitionCountry = scnr.nextLine();
        // get dog's training status and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the dog's training status?");
        String trainingStatus = scnr.nextLine();
        // get if dog is reserved and assign value
        System.out.println("Is this dog reserved?");
        boolean reserved = scnr.nextBoolean();
        // get country dog is serviced in and assign value
        System.out.println("Which country is the dog in service");
        String inServiceCountry = scnr.nextLine();

        // creates new dog object, includes data for attributes
        Dog dog = new Dog(name, breed, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate,
                           acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry);
        dogList.add(dog); // add new dog to Dog ArrayList
        System.out.println("This dog has been added to the Dog List");  // input validation
    }


    public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scnr) {
        // get monkey's name and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's name?");
        String name = scnr.nextLine();
        // input validation if monkey is already in monkeyList
        for (Monkey monkey : monkeyList) {
            if (monkey.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis monkey is already in our system\n\n");
                return; //returns to menu
            }
        }
        // get monkey's gender and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's gender?");
        String gender = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's age and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's age?");
        String age = scnr.nextLine();
        //get monkey's weight and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's weight?");
        String weight = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's acquisition date and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's acquisition date?");
        String acquisitionDate = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's acquisition country and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's acquisition country?");
        String acquisitionCountry = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's training status and assign value
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's training status?");
        String trainingStatus = scnr.nextLine();
        // get if monkey is reserved and assign value
        System.out.println("Is this monkey reserved?");
        boolean reserved = scnr.nextBoolean();
        // get country monkey is serviced in and assign value
        System.out.println("Which country is the monkey in service");
        String inServiceCountry = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's tail length and assign value
        System.out.print("What is the monkey's tail length");
        String tailLength = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's height and assign value
        System.out.print("What is the monkey's height");
        String height = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's body length and assign value
        System.out.print("What is the monkey's body length");
        String bodyLength = scnr.nextLine();
        // get monkey's species and assign value
        System.out.print("What is the monkey's species");
        String species = scnr.nextLine();

        // creates new monkey object, includes data for attributes
        Monkey monkey = new Monkey(name, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry, tailLength, height, bodyLength, species);
        monkeyList.add(monkey); // add new monkey to Monkey ArrayList
        System.out.println("This monkey has been added to the Monkey List");
    }
    // reserveAnimal method
    public static void reserveAnimal(Scanner scnr) {
        // get animal type
        System.out.println("Would you like to reserve a dog or a monkey?");
        String animalType = scnr.nextLine();
        // get country
        System.out.println("Which country will the " + animalType + " be serving in?");
        String serviceLocation = scnr.nextLine(); // correct variable??

        // if animal type is dog
        if (animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")) {
            // Search dog ArrayList for a dog that matches serviceLocation of country entered.
            for (Dog dog : dogList) {
                // if service location matches country and not reserved
                if (dog.getInServiceLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(serviceLocation) && !dog.getReserved()) {
                    // set reserved to true
                    dog.setReserved(true);
                    dog.setInServiceCountry(serviceLocation);
                    // output found message to user
                    System.out.println(dog.getName() + " has been reserved.");
                    return;

                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Search monkey ArrayList for a monkey that matches service location of country entered
            for (Monkey monkey : monkeyList) {
                // if service location matches country and not reserved
                if (monkey.getInServiceLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(serviceLocation) && !monkey.getReserved()) {
                    // set reserved to true
                    monkey.setReserved(true);
                    monkey.setInServiceCountry(serviceLocation);
                    // output found message to user
                    System.out.println(monkey.getName() + " has been reserved.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // printAnimals method
    public static void printAnimals(String printAnimals) {
        switch (printAnimals) {
            case "4":
                System.out.println("All dogs: ");
                // output all dogs in dogList
                //for (Dog dog: dogList) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); ++i) {
                    Dog dog = dogList.get(i);
                    System.out.print(dog.getName());
                }

                break;
            case "5":
                System.out.println("All monkeys: ");
                // output all monkeys in monkeyList
                for (Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
                    System.out.print(monkey.getName());
                }
                break;
            case "6":
                System.out.println("All available animals: ");
                // Output all animals that are not reserved
                for (Dog dog : dogList) {
                    if (!dog.getReserved()) {
                        System.out.println(dog);
                    }
                }
                for (Monkey monkey : monkeyList) {
                    if (!monkey.getReserved()) {
                        System.out.println(monkey);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input for printAnimals.");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the user's choice **before** the loop and then you don't update it again. Thus you loop forever with whatever that choice was. I would use a `do-while` instead.

```
// loop that displays the menu, accepts user inputs, takes appropriate action
do {
    menuChoice = scnr.nextLine();  // get menu choice from user
    // ...
        default:  // if user input is invalid, print message
            if(!menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
                System.out.println("\n Invalid input, enter 1-6 or q");
                displayMenu();  // call display menu method
                menuChoice = scnr.nextLine();  // get menu choice from user
            }
        break;
    }
} while(!menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
```